# Cannot connect to "myserver" error in IOS ad-hoc distribution

Tags: ios, iis-7, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I need to enable ad-hoc distribution for my IOS application. I have created a web site on IIS7 and added required MIME (.IPA & .PLIST) types. web site is enabled with SSL with a self signing certificate.

But when I click the download link on the device it says "Cannot connect to www1.myserver.biz.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Below is my .plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www1.myserver.biz/myapp.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.enterprise.xxx.myapp</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>myapp</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

HTML code for download like as follows

```
<div class="link"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www1.myserver.biz/myapp.plist">Tap Here to Install<br />myapp<br />On Your Device</a></div>
```

Comment: Make sure internet is working on device . Also did you try to access your server with test page like "www1.myserver.biz" is even working on the browser?

Comment: The default page is working on the device. but when I press the link to install the app, then I get this error message

Comment: Your plist and html code looks fine . You need check if you have uploaded your html page, plist and spa to correct directory on server

Comment: all 3 files there in the server. thanks for ur help

Comment: I have the same problem actually. Did you come to any conclusion?